# set tsconfig default path when importing

Tags: typescript

I have a react project that I setup in order to have an absolute path when I import which is "src".

Basically, when I compile, the following path is correct '

```
import RadarChart from 'src/utils/radarChart';
```

Everything looks fine, I compile it works, but TS throw me warning in visual code

all my import are saying

> Cannot find module

I tried setup ts config using

`"include": ["./", "src/] "./__tests__/**/*"]`
or

```
  {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./__tests__/**/*"]
```

but nothing happen.

Comment: Did you have a look at [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"baseUrl": "."` since you are trying to import from folder `src` in the root folder and not `src/src/`

Comment: it looks ok but, 

inside src I have multiple folder, and only src/components/ don't throw typescript error ,the rest (like src/download) are throwing the same error

Comment: What's the file extension of `radarChart`? And are you sure you are exporting `RadarChart` in `radarChart`?

Comment: it'S doing the same for my images/ folder and my data/ folder. He can only find the components. RadarChart is a .ts, the other one I import them with their extension (.json, .png)

Comment: Maybe try 

```include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]```